# How to remove repeated values and computing elapsed time in a dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a big pandas dataframe with several columns, for visual purposes I will put two columns but it is larger:

```
     ID      DATETIME   
    432 2012-05-11 19:22:18 
    432 2012-05-11 19:22:22 
    432 2012-05-11 19:22:48 
    432 2012-05-11 19:22:54 
    432 2012-05-11 19:22:55 
    432 2012-05-11 19:22:58 
    123 2012-05-11 20:59:57 
    123 2012-05-11 20:59:58 
    123 2012-05-11 11:00:00 
    123 2012-05-11 11:00:00 
    123 2012-05-11 11:00:30 
    123 2012-05-11 11:00:31 
    123 2012-05-11 11:00:34 
    123 2012-05-11 11:00:34 
    123 2012-05-11 11:01:15 
    123 2012-05-11 11:01:54 
    123 2012-05-11 11:01:54 
    432 2012-05-11 11:54:01
    432 2012-05-11 11:54:07
    432 2012-05-11 11:54:13
    432 2012-05-11 11:54:24
    432 2012-05-11 11:54:39
    432 2012-05-11 11:54:44
    432 2012-05-11 11:55:10 
    432 2012-05-11 11:55:12 
    432 2012-05-11 11:55:17 
    098 2012-05-11 22:49:07 
    098 2012-05-11 22:49:16 
    098 2012-05-11 22:49:17 
    098 2012-05-11 22:49:17
```

As you can see, I have several repeated IDs, how can I compress it into a single id with the amount of time that took in seconds? For example, this should be the expected output:

```
     ID  DATE           TIME    
    432 2012-05-11 (amount of time in sec)  
    123 2012-05-11 (amount of time in sec)  
    432 2012-05-11 (amount of time in sec)
    098 2012-05-11 (amount of time in sec)
```

I tried to first remove the duplicates by:

```
  df2 = df2.drop_duplicates(subset='rownum', keep='last')
```

However, I do not know how to compute the times and the removal of duplicated ids is not working. Any idea of how to get the previous "compression"?

Comment: is `amount of time in sec` supposed to be the `max(time) - min(time)` for each group of `id, date`? why does id 432 appear twice in the result? can you update the expected output with the actual expected output based on the sample data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IIUC using `diff` with `cumsum` create the group key , then we using `agg`

```
new_df=df.groupby([df['ID'].diff().ne(0).cumsum(),df.ID]).DATETIME.agg([np.ptp,lambda x : x.dt.date.iloc[0]])
new_df=new_df.assign(ptp=new_df.ptp.dt.total_seconds())
new_df
Out[45]: 
            ptp    <lambda>
ID ID                      
1  432     40.0  2012-05-11
2  123  35998.0  2012-05-11
3  432     76.0  2012-05-11
4  98      10.0  2012-05-11
```

Update

```
df['helperkey']=df['ID'].diff().ne(0).cumsum()
New_df=df.groupby(['helperkey','ID']).DATETIME.agg([np.ptp,lambda x : x.dt.date.iloc[0]]).reset_index()
New_df.merge(df.drop_duplicates(['helperkey','ID']),on=['ID','helperkey'],how='left')
new_df=new_df.assign(ptp=new_df.ptp.dt.total_seconds())
```

Comment: Thanks, this one works! However, is removing the other columns, is there any way of preserving the other cols and removing its duplicates as well?